# Erlang: Mnesia or Mysql?

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

What DBMS do you use with Erlang ? and Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an evaluation of DBMS in Erlang:

http://www.erlang-solutions.com/thesis/dbms_eval.html

UPDATE: Mind it's a bit out-of-date, but it could turn useful as a start.

Comment: The main problem with that link is that it deliberately avoids consideration of what is arguably the strongest candidate for use as a database from erlang: mnesia.

Answer (score 4):

Mnesia, because it's all native erlang, and being able to store erlang terms is just great. Speeds up development too.

I know of no other DMBS that can integrate so closely with the language (that one's easy, Mnesia is almost part of the language, a *Dict* on steroids). Of course, it's a bit low-level, so functions like full-text search have to be coded against it, but it wouldn't be that much fun otherwise (unless you can couple it with some other open-source full-text search engines).

But you have to judge the different options for yourself against your own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would use postgresql with the same code as this project. http://zotonic.com/ (just surf around for a sec, feel the low latency, I love it)

Postgresql will always be a little bit more mature than mysql. =)

It worth looking into. (Have not used it yet, but I will)